# Spring MVC - Keeping object state between ajax requests

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

Spring MVC 4.1

Hi,
I have a situation where, on a single page, there are several input fields. As the users enters numbers into these fields, a bunch of calculations will occur and update various other fields on the page.
I want this whole calculation model to take place in Java on the server-side. I really want to avoid replicating this logic in Javascript on the client.

What I envision is...

- User opens the page, the object that does the calculations (let's call it Calculator) is created and its initial state is set (many of its fields are pre-populated with values).
- This Calculator instance is stored and available for the duration of the user's time on that page.
- Whenever the user changes a value in an input field, that new value is sent to the server via ajax and plugged into our Calculator object. The Calculator, re-calculates the other fields based on the new state and returns the results to the page.
- The other fields on the page are updated accordingly.

The key here is that I'm not sending the state of all fields with each ajax request. I'm only sending the current value that was updated. Essentially, I'm trying to ensure that the form state and the Calculator state on the back-end are always synchronized.

I have looked into @SessionAttributes and @ModelAttribute.

The problem with @ModelAttribute, as I understand it, is that it will be re-created with each ajax request.

The problem with @SessionAttributes is that it is a session variable.  What if the user has two of these windows open? And how do I ensure the object is removed from the session when they leave the page? etc...

Maybe there's no magic Spring bullet and I just have to figure out the session variable thing. But any pointers on dealing with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

.1. Like you have said using the `@SessionAttributes`, however yes it suffers from the issue that you have mentioned, multiple instances of the same session will see the same variable.

.2. Store state somewhere else and re-hydrate the state using `@ModelAttribute` annotated method. I would personally prefer this approach, essentially when you create the form, create it with a identifier for the current state:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "form")
public String createForm(Model uiModel) {
    uiModel.addAttribute("calculationId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return "calculationpage/create";
}
```

Then for subsequent ajax requests, ensure your previous calculationId is sent across:

```
@ModelAttribute("calculationState")
public CalculationState rehydrateState(String calculationId) {
    //retrieve current state of calculation from some persistent store..
}

@RequestMapping("/calculate")
public String handleCalculation(@ModelAttribute("calculationState") CalculationState c) {
    //you will get a calculationstate with the delta's at this point..
}
```

.3. Another potential approach may be to use session but disambiguate different instances within the session with a custom id:

```
   public String handleCalculation(HttpSession session, @RequestParam("calcId") String calcId) {
     CalculationState calcState = (CalculationState) session.getAttribute("calculation" + calcId);
   }
```

Comment: Good info!  This will help me get started. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need any sort of persistent store outside session to store and retrieve the state of your calculator model. Like Biju said, I will go for solutions like No 2.